# Redux initial state for variable reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

In my program I have multiple grids, but they are very similar, so iIdecided to make one reducer for all of them to keep my code nice and DRY. When I dispatch event to change store I send grid name as argument along with payoload and everything writes to store under that grid name.

For example: If I send event to change grid header of catalog grid then store will look like this: (Lets persume users was already in store)

```
grid: {
    catalog: {
        headers: {
            some data
        }
    },
    users: {
        headers: {
            some other data
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I write modular initial state? Currently I have no initial state except grid names, because without them my code doesn't work. When I need to set something as initial, then I have to include it in my function `initializeGrid` which dispatches some events to set something similar to initial state.

But without initial state my reducer is pretty messy, because in almost every case i have to check if there is some state or if this is first entry.

Just know that i am not lazy but my initial state would be like 300 rows long and it would not be DRY :/

What is correct solution?

Comment: Please provide some code that goes along with your description.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an initial state other then {} ?

The reducer can just update the state with the required value. 
If the key exists, its value is updated, if it doesn't exist, it will be added.
Take a look at the following example:

```
let x = { "a" : { "b": 11 }}
let y = { ...x, "c" : { "d": 22 }}
let z = { ...y, "a": { "b": 33 }}
```

values are as following (omitted the "" for easier reading):

```
x: { a: { b: 11 }
y: { a: { b: 11 }, c: { d: 22 }}
z: { a: { b: 33 }, c: { d: 22 }}
```

Comment: As i said, i need initial state because when i want to change anything I have to check if there is value in that thing. And obviously I would prefer initial state before dispatching initialization function (performance drawback) And my reducer is object about 9 layers deep and it gets tideous :/